# How to sort an array of NSDate(in NSMutableArray)?

Tags: sorting, nsarray, nsdate

Can anyone show me how to sort an array(NSMutableArray) of NSDate in order for the actual dates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go just modify some part of code for your requirement

```
- (NSArray *)sortedWeightEntriesByWeightDate:(NSArray *)unsortedArray {

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

    @try {
        for(int i = 0; i < [unsortedArray count];i++) {

            NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            MyDataModal *entry = [unsortedArray objectAtIndex:i];       
            [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];       
            NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:entry.weightDate];        
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

            if(date) {  
                [dict setObject:entry forKey:@"entity"];        
                [dict setObject:date forKey:@"date"];       
                [tempArray addObject:dict];
            }
            [df release];
        }

        NSInteger counter = [tempArray count];
        NSDate *compareDate;
        NSInteger index;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < counter; i++) {
            index = i;
            compareDate = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"date"];        
            NSDate *compareDateSecond;

            for(int j = i+1 ; j < counter; j++) {
                compareDateSecond=[[tempArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"date"];
                NSComparisonResult result = [compareDate compare:compareDateSecond];
                if(result == NSOrderedDescending) {
                    compareDate = compareDateSecond;
                    index=j;
                }
            }
            if(i!=index)
                [tempArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:index];
        }


        NSInteger counterIndex = [tempArray count];
        for(int i = 0; i < counterIndex ; i++) {
            [sortedArray addObject:[[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"entity"]];
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"An exception occured while sorting weight entries by date");
    }
    @finally {
        return [NSArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want to use something like -[NSMutableArray sortUsingSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingSelector%3a) and pass in `@selector(compare:)`. Ie, assuming you had an `NSMutableArray` of `NSDates` named `*dateArray*:`

```
[dateArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: Thanks this method is useful, but for compare: selector, there is only one argument, something like compare:(NSDate *)other, but I need another date to compare.